# Datepicker doesn't work in visualforce pages

Tags: visualforce, javascript

For some reason date picker doesn't work and nothing pops up showing a javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at main.js:18
    at new DatePicker (main.js:647)
    at Function.DatePicker.getDatePicker (main.js:660)
    at Function.DatePicker.pickDate (main.js:661)
    at HTMLInputElement.onfocus (CaseDetailsWithFeed?id=500D000001PLHQM&sfdc.override=1:1)
.. and many others the same way
```

I'm using very simple page which replicates standard functionality:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="CaseDetailsWithFeedExtension" sidebar="false"> 
    <support:casefeed caseid="{!Case.Id}"/>
</apex:page>
```

I tried to include jquery ui and jquery libraries manually but didn't work. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Where is this page being used and are there any JS errors in console?

Comment: @RahulSharma I use it to override default case view and another error is Cannot read property 'currentStyle' of null which is repeated several times. Does this sound like a 'bug'?

Comment: Yes looks like a bug if you do not have any custom JavaScript conflicting with the standard functionality by any chance.

Comment: @NGix, are you using this page in the SF Console or in the SF1 app? Because if so, this can be the issue. 
Also, it can be a bug in the chatter component. I once had a bug with the chatter email publisher also (it didn't preformed  the search on the email addresses.)
I would recommend issuing a bug/raising a case with SF.